# Moving apps to folders within the app drawer using the stock launcher of Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, app-drawer

So on my Galaxy S4 I can open the Apps Overflow Menu (4x4 square-ish dots) and press the menu button (left of the Home) and choose edit. From there I can long press icons and put them into a folder on a particular page.

What I can't do is drag apps from page to page and place them in folders on different pages.

I would really like to have all my Verizon/Samsung apps in their own folders.

I feel the answer will be a resounding "you can't", but how can I put icons from different pages of the apps overflow menu into folders on a different page in this menu list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have an S4 (Build number I9505XXUBMGA) using the Nova launcher.

However, I've changed to the stock launcher, and testing your scenario. My apps are sorted alpabetically (View type > Alphabetical grid). So, I created 4 different folders that would be strategically placed in different pages.

In edit mode, I dragged 1 app to the every edge of the screen, and it moved to the next page. I looked for the folder and dropped it there. Success! :)

The key here is to drag it to the very edge of the screen. You will see a blue vertical line show up once you get to the very edge. Again, do not just move it within the page. Move it to the very edge.

Comment: Wow... when you say edge you mean edge lol. I thought I had held far enough over and it didn't seem to work but I just tried it again and realized it wasn't enough before. Thanks!

Comment: @TronicZomB You're welcome. Glad to be of help. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have my S4 in a lifeproof case so it is almost impossible ( or at least a real pain in the butt ) to slide all the way to the edge due to the case overlap :)

nother option is to go to the apps drawer ( the little grid ).. press the menu button (left of the Home) and choose edit, then click on the folder you want to put apps into ( or create one first, then choose edit, then click on it) and then in the little window that pops up, click on the "plus" icon... ( you only get this with folders ) then simply put a check-mark on all the apps you want in that folder ... you can slide from page to page, checking apps, and click save at the top when you are done.  Repeat for each folder you want to put apps into.

Answer (score 0):

To move apps within the app drawer to a folder within the app drawer, click the menu button and enter edit mode.